# Select and move events do not work in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have a class that inherits from `QGraphicItems` and another one that inherits from `QGraphicsScene`. I created a custom item and place them in my custom scene. 
Here are my event handler functions:

```
void Panel::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if (mouseEvent->button() != Qt::LeftButton)
        return;
    //my code 

    QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void Panel::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    //my code 

    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void Panel::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    //my code

    QGraphicsScene::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

However, those events do not seem to get called. I based my code on the `DiagramScene` example in Qt and the major difference is that my item inherits from `QGraphicsItem` rather than `QGraphicsPolygonItem`.

How can I get to handle the events properly?

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of `Panel::mousePressEvent()`, you end up calling `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()` after your own code has handled the event. The default implementation of `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()` will probably undo things you have done in your own code. As an example, the default implementation of `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()` will forward the event to the topmost item that accepts mouse events, and *that* item will become the mouse grabber. If your code expect some other things to happen such that another object should be the grabber (can't tell from the limited code you posted), then the call to the base class will undo what you did.

You shouldn't be calling the base class' event handlers if you wish to handle events yourself in a custom way.